# Running ng xi18n I get this error: "ERROR in Cannot read property 'loadChildren' of null"

Tags: angular

The error prevents all further work from `ng xi18n`.

The project works otherwise without problem or warnings in both dev mode and production mode.

In order to generate a `messages.xlf` file the workaround I found is to modify the `routes` in
`imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)]` to a very simple array (just for the purpose of running ng xi18n, then undo the change and build the real one).

Looks to me like a bug in ng...

Running on angular CLI 9.1.4, node 13.12.0, angular 9.1.4, MacOS.

Adding a limited extract of my routes:

```
export const alertRoutes: NavRoute[] = [
  {
    path: 'alert-center', data: { title: 'Alert center', permission: (r: UserAreaRights) => r.monitor > 0 }, canActivate: [CheckPermissionsGuard], children: [
      { path: 'dashboard', data: { title: 'Dashboard' }, component: DashboardComponent },
      { path: 'alerts', data: { title: 'Alerts' }, component: AlertsComponent }
    ]
  }
];
```

where `NavRoute` extends `RouteData`

Comment: Can you show your original routes?

Comment: Added some routes to the main posting.

Comment: Would you mind showing the code for the `NavRoute`-interface? I cannot get it working. Thank you!

Comment: I will prepare a small use case and send you the link

Comment: I published a minimal case that reproduces the error. It turns out the minimal condition involves a route definition that has a predicate inline function in its data code. See https://github.com/rsivan/route-error